# SSHFS on startup CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, centos6, sshfs

I edited the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` and added the following lines in order to mount a remote directory through sshfs at boot time:

```
su user -c "/usr/bin/sshfs -o idmap=user -o reconnect -o allow_other -o uid=500 -o gid=500  user@remote:/home/shares/allusers /home/user/mnt"
```

The problem is that is not mounting the directory on startup but when I execute this command manually after logging in everything works as expected an the directory is mounted.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

sshfs#user@remote:/home/shares/allusers /home/user/mnt" fuse defaults,idmap=user

to /etc/fstab

test it with mount -a if ok, reboot

Comment: I tried this but it is not working while rebooting because during that time I suppose the machine is not connected to the Internet.

Comment: Oh, righ. How about adding mount -a in rc.local?

Comment: hm.. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

rc.local will be executing as root so you'll need to make sure root has an SSH key that will work with the specified user at the remote host, or specify the key to use with `-o IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/my_key`*.

*Couldn't test this as it looks like my version of sshfs is too old to have the option.

Comment: Hm... I think you are right. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `mount -a` to `rc.local` as suggested by previous answers one can simply add `delay_connect` as a fstab option.

*(This could have been a comment, but my rep count is too low)*